# Can you help me debug this black-jack game?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1> Slap Jack </h1>
<p id="message"> </p>
<button type="button" onclick="investMoney()"> How much money are you betting? </button>
<script type="text/javascript">

var gambledMoney;
var money;
var investMoney = function() {
    gambledMoney = prompt("How much?");
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = gambledMoney;
};
var totalAmount;
var card;
var pullCard = function() {
    card = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14 + 1);
    totalAmount = +card;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = card + " " +
        "Do you want to pull again?";
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Total points" + " "
    totalAmount;
};

</script>
<p id="test"> </p>
<p id="p"> </p>
<button type="button" onClick="pullCard()"> click me to pull a card </button>


</body>
</html>
```

Card is random, and it will display card when you define it. I also want the total of how many points you have to be displayed. When I try to run the code, nothing happens.

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your code: `"Total points" + " " totalAmount;` – missing `+` sign.

Comment: You should use the developer console in the browser you're using.  It would normally tell you about errors in your code.

Comment: I recommend running your javascript code through [JSLint](http://jshint.com/) to find errors.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error on **Line # 22**
 The string concatenation sign [+] is missing.